# Create counter of consecutive runs of a certain value and ignoring rows based on a condition

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 987 × 2
   time   counts
   <time> <chr> 
 1 07:33  1358  
 2 07:34  1072  
 3 07:35  112   
 4 07:36  316   
 5 07:37  0     
 6 07:38  16    
 7 07:39  32    
 8 07:40  0     
 9 07:41  0     
10 07:42  92    
# … with 977 more rows
```

I need to make a new variable that assigns a unique value to consecutive runs and restarts when counts == 0. Also, if the counter starts with a 0 and the next two consecutive rows have values <100, I want the counter to ignore those two rows and treat them as 0. The same goes for one row of counts >1000. So, if the following row of row with counts == 0 is greater than 1000, I want to treat it as a 0.

So, these are the conditions for the counter:

- Restarts with 0
- Ignores rows (treats them as 0) if immediately after the row where counts == 0, two consecutive rows have counts <100 or one row has counts >1000.

I have to do this because I need to delete the rows that have 60 or more consecutive rows with counts == 0, BUT these rows can include two consecutive rows with counts <100 or one with counts >1000.

I'm not sure if this makes sense. Hopefully, it does!

I have tried the following:

```
db %>% 
  mutate(consec_id = rleid(counts==0))
```

But I don't know how to tell R to ignore certain rows based on specific conditions.

I also tried using a loop, but I am very new to loops, so I didn't get what I wanted:

```
# Loop through the dataset and update the "wear_status" variable
for (i in 2:nrow(day1)) {
  # Check if current counts = 0
  if (db$counts[i] == 0) {
    consec_counts <- 0
    db$wear_status[i] <- 0
  } else {
    # Check if current counts are between 1 and 100
    if (db$counts[i] > 1 || db$counts[i] < 100) {
      consec_counts <- consec_counts + 1
    } else {
      consec_counts <- 0
    }
    # Check if current counts > 100 or 3 consecutive rows of counts = 1 or 100
    if (db$counts[i] > 100 || consec_counts <= 2) {
      consec_counts <- 0
      db$wear_status[i] <- 1
    }
  }
}
```

This is my expected output:

```
# A tibble: 987 × 2
   time   counts  counter
   <time> <chr> 
 1 07:33  1358     1
 2 07:34  1072     1
 3 07:35  112      1  
 4 07:36  316      1
 5 07:37  0        2
 6 07:38  16       2  
 7 07:39  32       2  
 8 07:40  0        2
 9 07:41  0        2
10 07:42  92       3
11 07:43  80       3
12 07:44  78       3
13 07:45  0        4
# … with 977 more rows
```

Thank you!

Comment: It seems like rows 5,6,7 illustrate the "0 followed by two consecutive values < 100", and we see that the counter does not increment after the 0. Why doesn't this apply to rows 9,10,11. Row 9 has counts = 0 and the two rows immediately after it have values < 100 (rows 10 and 11 has values 92 and 80), but here the counter does increment. Why?

Comment: Hi Gregor! It doesn't apply to rows 9, 10 and 11 because row 12 has counts < 100, so three consecutive rows with values < 100. The counter should ignore the values only if no more than 2 consecutive rows have values <1000 or one row with value >1000. Makes sense? I know it's confusing...

Comment: Sorry, I meant "no more than 2 consecutive rows have values <100 or one row with value >1000"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something to try without using a loop.

You have 3 conditions that would result in the `counts` value becoming zero:

1. If the prior value is 0, the current is < 100, the following is < 100, and the one after that (2 values after the current value) is 0.
2. If the prior to the prior value is 0, the prior value is < 100, the current value is < 100 and the following value is 0.
3. If the previous value is 0, the current is greater than 1000, and the following value is 0.

You can use `lag` and `lead` to look at prior and following values. If you use a number, such as `lag(counts, n = 2)` that will consider 2 values away (n is the number of positions to `lag` or `lead` by).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  mutate(new_counts = ifelse(
    (lag(counts) == 0 & counts < 100 & lead(counts) < 100 & lead(counts, 2) == 0) |
    (lag(counts, 2) == 0 & lag(counts) < 100 & counts < 100 & lead(counts) == 0) |
    (lag(counts) == 0 & counts > 1000 & lead(counts) == 0),
    0,
    counts
  )) %>%
  mutate(counter = rleid(new_counts == 0))
```

**Output**

```
    time counts new_counts counter
1  07:33   1358       1358       1
2  07:34   1072       1072       1
3  07:35    112        112       1
4  07:36    316        316       1
5  07:37      0          0       2
6  07:38     16          0       2
7  07:39     32          0       2
8  07:40      0          0       2
9  07:41      0          0       2
10 07:42     92         92       3
11 07:43     80         80       3
12 07:44     78         78       3
13 07:45      0          0       4
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(time = c("07:33", "07:34", "07:35", "07:36", "07:37", 
"07:38", "07:39", "07:40", "07:41", "07:42", "07:43", "07:44", 
"07:45"), counts = c(1358L, 1072L, 112L, 316L, 0L, 16L, 32L, 
0L, 0L, 92L, 80L, 78L, 0L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your help. The code works when one row < 100 (prior and following number 0) but not when two consecutive rows have values <100. Any idea why? So, in my output, rows 6 and 7 do not become 0.

Comment: @marcela1510 I just noticed - is your `counts` column character value, not numeric? If so, you may want to make it numeric. Or describe what other values might be in that column to clarify. Also, did you try with my `df` posted in my answer with the code above? I just tried again and I got the same correct result.